# Magento 2 - How to add specific base url for store

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, base-url, store-code

In Magento 2 I try to add specific base url for store view.

This is my configuration :

My website 1 contains two store view :

- Store view 1 : **my_store_view_1**
- Store view 2 : **my_store_view_2**

Base urls secure unsecure are configured like this :

- my_store_view_1 : **mydomain.com/fr/**
- my_store_view_2 : **mydomain.com/nl/**

I have created two subfolders in magento root :

- <magento_root>/**fr**/
- <magento_root>/**nl**/

Each folder contains copy of root .htacces and index.php with :

```
<?php 

require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'my_store_view_1';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

When I visit *"mydomain.com"* I 'm successfully redirected to *"mydomain.com/fr/"* but only homepage is working, other pages are 404 not found.

When I visit *"mydomain.com/nl/"* I'm redirected automatically to *"mydomain.com/fr/"*

Do you know what is missing in my configuration ?
Thanks

Comment: Check https://devhooks.in/blog/setup-multi-store-multi-domain-magento-2 hope it'll help you.

Comment: @Mayank-Dolphin thanks but it doesn't work. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] return only domain and not complete url with "/fr/" or "/nl/"

Comment: Are you using the same domain for both store views?

Comment: @Mayank-Dolphin Yes same domain fro both store views :  mydomain.com/fr/ and mydomain.com/nl/

Answer (score 1):

As per your Comment You just need to enable only **Add Store Code to Urls = Yes**.

Under `Admin > Store > Configuration > Web > URL Option > Add Store Code to Urls = Yes.`

Comment: No because my store view codes are not just only "fr" and "nl" it's "my_store_view_1" and "my_store_view_1" and I can't change these store code for other reasons. I want to change base_url and not enable Add Store Code to Urls